# Push Notification "willPresent" not called but "didReceive" works

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, sendbird

I'm working on an app that handles push notifications.

For some reason,

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
```

Works as expected, but

```
func userNotificationCenter( _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
```

is never called.

Anyone ever come across this situation?

All the usual suspects are in place:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

is set in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        center.requestAuthorization(options:options) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    completion(granted)
                }
            }
        }
```

is returning true (permission granted)

Other items worth mentioning:

- The Push notifications are sent via SendBird
- When the app is in the background, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Times and again, read the documentation.

Apple states for `func userNotificationCenter( _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)`:

> Asks the delegate how to handle a notification that arrived while the app was running in the foreground.

That is, only when your app is running in FORGROUND and you get a notification will the system call this method to ask you whether this notification should still be shown to the user since they're already inside your app. You can call the completionHandler and pass in options like `alert` and `sound` so the user will still see the banner and hear the sound. If you only pass back `sound`, then the user sees no banner and only hears the notification sound.

Comment: This was implemented properly "completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])"

Comment: Yes, and when you say it's not called, are you in FOREGROUND? Is your app running in foreground when the notification arrives?

Comment: Yes, I am in the foreground and that delegate method is not called. I've found other posts that suggest it will not be called unless there is a "body" in the payload.

Comment: Good to hear that you've figured it out! :)

Comment: I have this issue do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What is your issue? @Ryan110

Comment: remote notification is working but will present is not calling at all